# How to make use of jquery script in react component?

Tags: jquery, html, reactjs, drag-and-drop, draggable

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var source;
        var destination;
        var fn = function(event, ui) {
            toDrop = $(ui.draggable).clone();
            if ($("#droppable").find("li[uniqueIdentity=" + toDrop.attr("uniqueIdentity") + "]").length <= 0) {
                $("#droppable").append(toDrop);
            }
            else
                return false;
        };
        $("#draggable li").draggable({
            helper: 'clone'
        });
        $("#droppable").droppable({ drop: fn });
    });
</script>
```

I am using drap and drop feature by using this jquuey in html its working properly how to make use of this in react component.

Comment: You don't need to mix jquery with React, you can use the npm package https://github.com/react-dnd/react-dnd

Comment: As a friend above said, you should not mix react with Jquery. There is no need, instead of it search for 3d part npm library to handle that.

Answer (score 0):

you can import the npm dependency as

```
npm install jquery
```

and then in your component you can import it as

```
import $ from "jquery"
```

and then you can write your code using$ as $(document).ready(function() {)};

Here is a workaround for jquery in npm https://github.com/reactjs/react-rails/issues/209